# Summarising Precision/Recall Measures in Multi-class Problem

Tags: classification, accuracy, precision-recall, multi-class

I have a hierarchical multi-class classification system, that classifies records into about 500 different categories. I want to summarise the performance of the classifier in a simple way.

A measure of accuracy on validation data is easy to implement: correctly coded/all coded. For each class, we can look at binary measures of precision and recall to summarise the performance relative to that class.

However, there doesn't seem to be a generally accepted way to combine binary precision and recalls into summaries of precision and recall across the entire set of classes. There appear to be a few ways to approach this summary:

1. Take a simple average (arithmetic/geometric/harmonic) of each class's precision/recall.
2. Take a weighted average (weighted by number of examples, etc) of each class's precision/recall.
3. Use bookmaker's informedness/markedness which seems to have a natural generalisation in the multiclass context.

Are there advantages to using one of these approaches particularly? Is there a generally accepted way to do this that I've just been missing?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-do-you-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-co

Comment: @Brandmaier Thanks for your comment. That's not really the same question - the question there is about computing the binary precision/recalls, which I'm comfortable with. I'm asking for good practice in summarising all of the binary precisions/recalls into a single measure over all of the classes.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there isn't a "de facto" way of calculating precision and recall for multi-class classification.

Your approaches are what I too would try:

1. Class-wise [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean).
2. Class-wise [weighted harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#Weighted_harmonic_mean) (if the classes are imbalanced). With a weight equal to the class imbalance (i.e. class weight = number of class examples / number of total examples)
3. Class-wise [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) (another approach if the classes are imbalanced).

There are also other metrics to evaluate the performance of your mode, besides precision and recall:

- [Multi-class version of ROC curve](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1010920819831). A [tutorial](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~flach/ICML04tutorial/) is also available.
- Generalized F1-score, G-mean, etc.