# Average of precision and recall

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall

A machine learning model is outputting precision and recall for a two-class classification problem (0 and 1) like this:

```
Confusion matrix:
[[136  21]
  41   6]]

Precision: [0.768 0.128]
Recall: [0.866 0.222]
Accuracy: 0.696
```

There are two measures for both precision and recall: The first measure for the 0 class and the second for 1 class. Is it okay to take the average of these? E.g. precision as a whole is `0.768+0.128 / 2 = 0.448`? And similarly with recall?

Comment: Can you share the code outputting these numbers? or just confirm that these are from sklearn. also are these two ok/not ok predictions or conceptually these are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING**: Average of precision/recall is totally different concept from Average Precision(AP) [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJnqikvfj2AhV-lGoFHWQWBi8QFnoECAgQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjonathan-hui.medium.com%2Fmap-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173&usg=AOvVaw2aBoCeFr12E_V0sGXXX0G0).

Based on the question, we will talk about the Average of precision and recall.

you are partially correct; if

```
      Predicted 0 , Predicted 1 
True 0 [[136             21]     [[TP  FN]
True 1   41              6]]       FP  TN]]
```

Then precision for each class(row) is ( Mi,i / sigma(j) Mji), So for:

> class 0: 136/ 136+41 (0.76)
>
> class 1: 6 / 6+21 ( 0.22)

for recall, the same happens, but the denominator will be on rows, i.e. ( Mi,i / sigma(j) Mij)

> class 0: 136/ 136+21 (0.86)
>
> class 1: 6 / 6+41 ( 0.12)

Then you can average on each group to have overall precision/recall.

Check [Table III](http://rali.iro.umontreal.ca/rali/sites/default/files/publis/SokolovaLapalme-JIPM09.pdf) of this paper (referred to as Precision_M and recall_M):

[image]

More precisely, you are doing macro-averaging.

in code, you can have :

```py
cm = confusion_matrix(labels, predictions)
recall = np.diag(cm) / np.sum(cm, axis = 1)
precision = np.diag(cm) / np.sum(cm, axis = 0)

#overall precision/recall
np.mean(precision)
np.mean(recall)
```

[Readmore](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-do-you-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-co)