# Measuring response bias from a confusion matrix

Tags: classification, signal-detection

Given a confusion matrix of a binary classifier, what are the best measures of response bias towards one of the classes?

One idea that comes to mind is Signal Detection Theory's criterion, but this measure assumes a Gaussian noise model.

Is there a more straightforward, well-tested measure of response bias? For example, we could divide the number of predicted positives (TP + FP) by the number of positives (TP + FN), but I'm not sure that such a ratio would be "well behaved".

Comment: A confusion matrix can be transformed into an estimate of the joint PMF between the prediction variable and the ground truth variables. See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/583420/296197) for details. Therefore, one possibility is to transform a given confusion matrix into an estimate of a joint PMF, set up another ground truth or “target” PMF that represents some sort of response bias, and then measure the statistical distance between these two PMFs. For example, using the [Hellinger distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python package [sdt_metrics](https://rogerlew.github.io/sdt-metrics/#nonparametric-metrics-of-response-bias) by Roger Lew implements several non-parametric response bias measures. Unfortunately, the package is not maintained, but the references are still useful.

One of these references is an empirical study comparing five response bias measures:

> See, J. E., Warm, J. S., Dember, W. N., and Howe, S. R. (1997).
> Vigilance and signal detection theory: An empirical evaluation of five
> measures of response bias. https://doi.org/10.1518/001872097778940704

Among the parametric response bias measures, they recommend B"D:
$$B’’_D = \frac{(1-H)(1-FA)-(H)(FA)}{(1-H)(1-FA)+(H)(FA)}$$

Note that care must be taken when $H$ (hit rate) or $FA$ (false alarm rate) are at their boundaries:

> Hautus, M.J. Corrections for extreme proportions and their biasing
> effects on estimated values of d′. Behavior Research Methods,
> Instruments, & Computers 27, 46–51 (1995).
> https://doi.org/10.3758/BF03203619

Answer (score -1):

I'll expand on my comment here. This answer was partially adapted from [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/583420/296197).

Let $Y$ represent a class label and $\hat Y$ represent a class prediction. In the binary case, let the two possible values for $Y$ and $\hat Y$ be $0$ and $1$, which represent the classes. Next, suppose that the confusion matrix for $Y$ and $\hat Y$ is:

|  | $\hat Y = 0$ | $\hat Y = 1$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $Y = 0$ | 10 | 20 |
| $Y = 1$ | 30 | 40 |

With hindsight, let us normalize the rows and columns of this confusion matrix, such that the sum of all elements of the confusion matrix is $1$. Currently, the sum of all elements of the confusion matrix is $10 + 20 + 30 + 40 = 100$, which is our normalization factor. After dividing the elements of the confusion matrix by the normalization factor, we get the following normalized confusion matrix:

|  | $\hat Y = 0$ | $\hat Y = 1$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $Y = 0$ | $\frac{1}{10}$ | $\frac{2}{10}$ |
| $Y = 1$ | $\frac{3}{10}$ | $\frac{4}{10}$ |

With this formulation of the confusion matrix, we can interpret it as an estimate of the joint probability mass function (PMF) of $Y$ and $\hat Y$. This interpretation allows us to measure how often a certain class is predicted. For example, suppose we wanted to compute $P(\hat{Y} = 1)$, which is how often the classifier predicts class $1$. Using the law of total probability, we can compute this as $P(\hat{Y} = 1) = P(\hat{Y} = 1,Y = 1) + P(\hat{Y} = 1,Y = 0) = \frac{4}{10} + \frac{2}{10} = \frac{6}{10}$. Therefore, the classifier predicts class $1$ about $60\%$ of the time. Note, however, that these are all estimates.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, how exactly would you set these target PMFs? I'm looking for established methods for response bias quantification.